# Why would a .Bat file work fine locally, but not work when invoked remotely?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .Bat file for testing that will kill my Chrome browser:

```
@cls
@echo You are about to kill Chrome
tskill "chrome"
```

It works fine when invoked locally. Chrome dies. If I invoke that exact .Bat file from another machine via psexec (of PsTools):

```
psexec 10.60.90.10 -u admin -p pizza1234 "C:/myBatfile.bat"
```

I get an error, saying:

```
Could not find process: chrome
```

Any idea why invoking that .bat file remotely would cause this error? The "local" machine is Windows Server 2008, the remote ("invoking") machine is Windows 7.

---SOLUTION---
The /A flag looks through all sessions. Thanks for your help.

```
tskill "chrome" /A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psexec utilizes a service on the target machine to execute the command. Services live in a separate Windows session than the interactive session where your chrome process is running. When executing through psexec, the bat file will search the service session for a chrome.exe process and there is none.

Comment: Thanks Anders. Would you suggest I use SSH to invoke .bat files on remote machines to avoid this problem?

Comment: The SSH server would probably also be running as a service - in the service session so it would have the same problem. You should adjust your .bat file to search all processes, not just the ones of the current session.

Comment: Thanks Anders. Are there any obscure terms I should search to target solving this problem? Otherwise, I'm going for ".bat file search all processes". Let me know if you don't think that will get me where I need to be. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

psexec runs the specified command on the remote machine, not the local machine.  It does not pull the remote file to the local machine and run it locally.  To do that, run the .bat file directly like you normally would, but use a UNC path to refer to it, eg:

```
\\10.60.90.10\SomeShareName\myBatfile.bat
```

Comment: Hi Remy- I think the default behavior is to run the file locally. You can set a flag that will cause psexec to copy the file first. Not sure if that's what you're talking about, but the /A flag (see above) was the trick. Thanks for your help!